# Sensing NES controller plugged in with Arduino

Tags: arduino, controller

The NES controller is a simple parallel-in-serial-out chip with clock, latch and data pins exposed, as well as 5 V and GND through its connector.

The thing is (and I already researched but I haven't found any "good" methods) I'd like to detect when it is plugged in.

I'm not good in electronics.

I've seen a solution adding a transistor, but wouldn't it be possible to add a resistor from controller's GND pin to an input, so it acts kind of a pull-down, and you can read the voltage coming from that GND pin?

Is there any solution?

Also I've seen a possible solution using a 5 V Zener diode, but I don't know how I would connect it.

My idea is to have a pin to sense it, as other solutions suggest powering the Arduino with a transistor so when current is drawn by the controller Arduino is powered, but I need Arduino to be powered always as I'll have 2 controller ports on the same board, and I need to enable/disable joysticks in my PC programatically.

Comment: What are you proposing with a resistor? It's hard to envision what you mean. Could you draw it?

Comment: @Hearth well, 5V from arduino would go to 5V of the controller, and GND pin of the controller would go to GND pin of the arduino (to get usb power). I tought maybe between the GND pin of the controller and GND pin of the arduino adding a resistor to a pin? Or something similar? Again, I can't imagine a way.

Comment: pin 5 and pin 6 in the connector are unused by the controller

Comment: @jsotola I considred that, but those pins are not internally connected, just floating, so I cannot measure continuity through them

Comment: @maduranma Are you talking about using a current shunt? You could do that, but you'd definitely need a current sense amplifier attached to it if you don't want to use such a large resistor that it just doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Hearth to be fair, I just don't know, I'm really new, the what to use is what I don't know for that purpose, it was just an idea that probably makes no sense :'(

Comment: @maduranma Is this just the old 'box' controllers sold with the NES in the US? If so, those use a 4021, I think. Since the way that the controller works, it reads "1" for buttons that are not pressed, then a controller that is just sitting there should feed back a series of 1's to you when you latch and clock them out. (The NES hardware would invert them back for the 6502 software. But you don't care about that.) If there is nothing connected, you can arrange things so that you will read "0" bits, instead. (It's very unlikely that a connected controller will have all 8 buttons held down.)

Comment: @periblepsis Well, I do have the european version, but I think it's the same. To be fair I haven't tried it. The thing is, if the data pin is floating, then I'd get random 1s and 0s, so I might read 8 1s in a row, can I pull up the data pin?

Comment: @maduranma If the 4021 is present then the pin you will be reading is actively driven. The 4021 can sink and source current (in the small mA area.) If there is nothing connected at the connector (no 4021, and power isn't being drawn) then the pin will be very high impedance (near infinity) and you can tether it lightly to ground without harm. You could also just detect current being drawn on the +5V power pin, too. That should also be another way. Nothing connected means no current being drawn.

Comment: You could also theoretically add a mechanical switch to the connector that's pressed by inserting it (barrel plugs and phono jacks usually have these; the NES controller connector doesn't without modifying it though).

Comment: @periblepsis I tought of that, but I don't know how to design a circuit which senses if there's power draw. If arduino could provide enough power through a pin, I guess it would be enough with a pull up resistor, but I read the controller draws about 250mA, which is higher thant the pin max current.

Comment: @maduranma The 4021 draws microamps, quiescent. Even with the data out pin active, I don't imagine the controller draws 3 orders of magnitude more than the datasheet annotates. What's the source of that number? Also, I'd recommend just tethering the data line with a high-value resistor (47 k, perhaps) to ground. Easier and cheaper than bothering with detecting current at the power pin.

Comment: @periblepsis I cannot find where I saw it, as I've been researching a few hours. But the reason I guess is because for each button there are pull up resistors which adds power draw

Comment: @maduranma I think this calls for some testing on your end. You should have a multimeter (or a power supply that also includes a meter telling you the current draw, when powering a device) and should be able to clear up the issue, quickly.

Comment: @periblepsis okey, I have it at home, I'm going later and will measure the power draw of the controller when powering it with 5V and when pressing buttons. Thanks!

Comment: @maduranma I think you're misunderstanding the point of pull-up resistors, because you keep using the term in a way that seems nonsensical to me.

Comment: @maduranma What did you measure?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Arduino you have: sense the controller's output (SDO) pin.

Easiest way is to set passive pull-up and pull-down, and check if the input pin level follows the pulls or not.

That is:

```
 SDO   |  pin setting  | pin level
-------+---------------+----------
 open  | weak pullup   |    1
       | weak pulldown |    0
-------+--------------------------
driven | weak pullup   |    0
 '0'   | weak pulldown |    0
-------+--------------------------
driven | weak pullup   |    1
 '1'   | weak pulldown |    1
```

You won't know in general whether the controller is driving '0' or '1', but the fact that it doesn't change with pull direction is the part that matters.

If your Arduino doesn't support weak pull-down, you can approximate this by setting the pin (strong) high or low (i.e. DDR = '1') for a few cycles then hi-Z (DDR = '0') immediately after.  (You probably can't assign for a few cycles within the Arduino library calls, but as fast as can be, in that case.)  Then read the pin value immediately after -- capacitance will hold it there for a short time.

Meanwhile, preferably connect the controller to the SPI peripheral for easy use.  It can also be bit-banged (manually set SCK high/low, read SDO), which is a bit of a bother to implement, but nonetheless usable.

Apparently there are some other signals on the connector as well, which might be useful.  Dunno.

Comment: Hi, there's one more handicap to that, I'm gonna have 2 controller ports on the same Arduino (this is a requirement as it will go inside my computer and I only have a half USB-2 header available in the motherboard (so I can only connect one arduino).
The Arduino I'm using is the Pro micro, problem is I've got to do this twice, so I cannot use SPI pins

Comment: I mean you can use SPI for one, but duplicating the bit-bang code for two would be easier, yes.

Comment: problem is I cannot use SDO port for both, how would I do it without it?

Comment: You just asked about detection. Bit-bang serial is a separate question (and I suspect already well answered, search around).